# Opening directories in vim troubles

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Why do my vim plugins not open at startup unless I open vim like this:

```
❯ cd path/to/directory
path/to/directory❯ vim
```

Why can't I open it like this?

```
❯ vim path/to/directory
```

Comment: I have a feeling you're talking about a specific plugin (more specifically an ftplugin). ftplugins are loaded only when files with specific filetypes are loaded.

Comment: What is `path/to/file❯vim` even doing?

Comment: The plugins I have installed are:
   Vundle 
   Nerdtree
   Tagbar
   Ctrlp
   Syntastic
   Vim-airlineschemes
   Bufexplorer
   SuperTab
   PHPComplete
   Easy Motion
@DhruvaSagar

And my apologies for not making it clear! That's just my prompt. I got tired of the huge line preceding my commands. You could imagine the `❯` as a `$` @FDinoff

Comment: What does "plugins do not open" mean? Aren't the plugins loaded, or are you missing any default actions (which?)

Comment: "Plugins do not open" meaning if I navigate inside the directory and then type `vim` eg: `path/to/directory; vim` works, vim will add Nerd Tree in a buffer to the left. I basically have a lot of visual formatting to it, but when I try to access the directory by typing `vim path/to/directory` it will open vim but without the buffer opened, etc. :)

Comment: Please show us how that automatic open of NERDTree is implemented (in your .vimrc); if is has a check for `argc()`, that might explain it.

Comment: [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/alex-cory/10251197) so that it has better formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your autocmd that automatically opens NERDTree checks for the number of arguments (`argc()`), and only opens NERDTree if none are specified:

```
" Only open nerdtree if no file was specified on startup
function! StartUpNerdtree()
    if 0 == argc()
        NERDTree
    end
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call StartUpNerdtree()
```

That makes sense in a way: If you pass a file(s) when opening Vim, you probably don't need the directory browser. Now, to tweak this function to what you want, the conditional needs to be extended to check for a single directory argument: Replace

```
    if 0 == argc()
```

with

```
    if 0 == argc() || 1 == argc() && isdirectory(argv(0))
```

Note: What exactly happens with this change depends on your (NERDTree) configuration; you didn't include this in the question nor did you specify the desired behavior. I hope you get the idea and can tweak this according to your expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the `isdirectory` tip. That's exactly what I was looking for.